# size_t vs int warning

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

I am getting following warning always for following type of code.

```
std::vector v;
for ( int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
}
```

`warning C4267: 'initializing' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data`

I understand that `size()` returns `size_t`, just wanted to know is this safe to ignore this warning or should I make all my loop variable of type `size_t`

Comment: I believe it is safe to do so, although I'd be interested in learning what exception may make this unsafe.

Comment: @Atticus: If the size is greater than `MAX_INT`, then you have a possible denial of service (because the loop would loop forever)

Comment: Thanks @Billy this will be helpful for my future developments

Comment: @Billy I believe `i` would go negative (INT_MAX+1) and then cause an assertion failure trying to access a negative index. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Marlon: 1. Who says there was an assertion trying to access a negative index? `std::vector::operator[]` certainly does not have one. Attempting to access a negative index is undefined behavior, which is even worse than the denial of service I already mentioned. (I guess overflowing the signed integer was already undefined behavior...) 2. That only is the case if you attempted to access an index of the vector in any case. It's possible you wanted a loop the size of the vector but not actually accessing the vector. 3. Even if there is an assert there, it obviously won't affect release builds.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure if it was UB. Thank you for your expertise ;)

Comment: @Marlon, @Billy: unsigned integers overflow is safe (the integer loop back to 0) but signed integers overflow is UB. On some architecture, the latter may trigger a hardware exception.

Comment: @Matthieu: Did I say otherwise?

Comment: You should be using `++i` (even though it won't matter for `int`)

Comment: @Billy: I took the `guess` as a question, sorry :/

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you might need to hold more than `INT_MAX` items in your vector, use `size_t`.  In most cases, it doesn't really matter, but I use `size_t` just to make the warning go away.

Better yet, use iterators:

```
for( auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it )
```

(If your compiler doesn't support C++11, use `std::vector<whatever>::iterator` in place of `auto`)

C++11 also makes choosing the best index type easier (in case you use the index in some computation, not just for subscripting `v`):

```
for( decltype(v.size()) i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i )
```

Comment: And you can also use a range-based for loop: `for(auto& e : v) { }`.

Comment: @Mark: Maybe, maybe not.  If you need the index variable, the range-based loop isn't as attractive.  Iterators are also needed for some operations, such as `insert()`.

Comment: Can alternatively use `for (decltype(v)::size_type i = 0;  i < v.size(); ++i)`

Comment: @MattEding: For standard containers and other types which expose a `size_type` typedef, you could.  But there would be no point; my code is shorter and will work anywhere yours does.

Answer (score 18):

***What is `size_t`?***
`size_t` corresponds to the integral data type returned by the language operator `sizeof` and is defined in the  header file (among others) as an `unsigned integral type`.

***Is it okay to cast `size_t` to `int`?***
You could use a cast if you are sure that size is never going to be > than `INT_MAX`.

<strike>If you are trying to write a portable code, it is **not** safe because,</strike>

`size_t` in `64 bit Unix` is `64 bits`
`size_t`in `64 bit Windows` is `32 bits`

So if you port your code from Unix to WIndows and if above are the enviornments you will lose data.

***Suggested Answer***

Given the caveat, the suggestion is to make `i` of `unsigned integral type` or even better use it as type `size_t`.

Comment: `size_t` in 64-bit Windows is 64 bits.  You're thinking of `long`.  What he should be using is std::vector<T>::size_type, or better yet, iterators.

Comment: Actually, making it unsigned will not fix this warning. C4267 is [conversion to size_t loses data on 64 bit platforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kck0s93(v=vs.80).aspx). You are thinking of [signed/unsigned mismatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y92ktdf2.aspx).

Comment: or thinking of wchar_t

Comment: @CoryNelson: I just read in a similar SO post that std::vector<T>::size_type is equivalent to size_t and size_t (or even better std::size_t) can/should be preferred.

Answer (score 11):

> is this safe to ignore this warning or should I make all my loop variable of type size_t

No. You are opening yourself up to a class of integer overflow attacks. If the vector size is greater than `MAX_INT` (and an attacker has a way of making that happen), your loop will run forever, causing a denial of service possibility.

Technically, `std::vector::size` returns `std::vector::size_type`, though.

You should use the right signedness for your loop counter variables. (Really, for most uses, you want unsigned integers rather than signed integers for loops anyway)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you're mixing two different data types. On some architectures, `size_t` is a 32-bit integer, on others it's 64-bit. Your code should properly handle both.

since `size()` returns a `size_t` (*not int*), then that should be the datatype you compare it against.

```
std::vector v;
for ( size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternate view from Bjarne Stroustrup:
http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#simple-program

```
for (int i = 0; i<v.size(); ++i) cout << v[i] << '\n';
```

> Yes, I know that I could declare i to be a vector::size_type
>   rather than plain int to quiet warnings from some hyper-suspicious
>   compilers, but in this case,I consider that too pedantic and
>   distracting.

It's a trade-off. If you're worried that v.size() could go above 2,147,483,647, use size_t. If you're using i inside your loop for more than just looking inside the vector, and you're concerned about subtle signed/unsigned related bugs, use int. In my experience, the latter issue is more prevalent than the former. Your experience may differ.

Also see [Why is size_t unsigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168079/why-is-size-t-unsigned).

Comment: I think the advice by Stroustrup is really only meant for beginners and not to confuse them even more (i.e. for "start of semesters"-type people). I think in any production code (and in later lectures) one should teach to use std::size_t.

Comment: "in this case" is key there.  Also, the language has evolved a bit since Stroustrup wrote that, too.  Today you'd probably use a range-for loop or an algorithm or iterators, and completely avoid the problem.  The problem with silencing the allegedly "hyper suspicious warnings" in order to allow code like this, you lose the power of those warnings to point to you at other parts of your code where there are real problems.  Production code deserves all the help the compiler can offer.