# Why does shared_ptr<T>::use_count() return a long instead of an unsigned type?

Tags: c++, c++14, shared-ptr

shared_ptr observers 20.8.2.2.5 C++14 Final Draft (n4296)

> ```
>    long use_count() const noexcept;
> ```
>
> Returns: the number of `shared_ptr` objects, `*this` included, that share ownership with `*this`, or 0 when `*this` is empty.
>
> [Note: `use_count()` is not necessarily efficient. — end note]

Comment: I wonder what the defined behaviour is if the count exceeds `LONG_MAX`

Comment: I guess by that point the software is knackered in other ways

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to this page

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1450.html

> The return type of use_count is signed to avoid pitfalls such as
>   p.use_count() > -1 evaluating to false.

with a reference to

> John Lakos, Large-Scale C++ Software Design, section 9.2.2, page 637, Addison-Wesley, July 1996, ISBN 0-201-63362-0.

Basically, it looks like a nanny-grade decision, tailored for freshman year software developers.

Comment: hmmm... looks like my third bullet.

Comment: An easy to use interface, whatever were they thinking?

Comment: The Lakos book is excellent and is probably the book that influenced my C++ the most. One rule is no unsigned types in interfaces. That's not a "nanny-grade decision, tailored for freshman year software developers", that's deep advice about how to scale software development and keep things reliable.

Comment: Note that immediately after the quote given in this answer [N1450](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1450.html) also states the following: "*The long return type of use_count does not imply that implementations should always use long for the reference count. In some cases, size_t or its signed equivalent may be a better candidate for the actual type used underneath.*" The bad choice for this return type should be no suprise as N1450 also states: "*use_count is provided as a testing and debugging aid rather than for use in production code.*"

Comment: The section 9.2.3 of that book reads: "Guideline: Avoid using `long` in the interface;".

Answer (score 17):

The reason is that the most appropriate type for a counter of this kind is a regular `signed` integer, even if this counter is never going to get below 0.

Why a counter should be `unsigned`? The fact that it cannot become negative is not a valid excuse at all given current **real meaning** of `unsigned` for the language.

`unsigned` for C++ doesn't mean an "integer number that cannot be negative". To understand why this definition simply doesn't make sense consider that

- The difference of two `unsigned` is `unsigned`
- The addition of an `unsigned` with a `signed` is `unsigned`
- An `unsigned` value is never bigger than -1

None of the above makes any sense if you consider `unsigned` to mean "non-negative".

Using `unsigned` for `size_t` was a mistake (see for example [Why is size_t unsigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10168079/320726)), only partially* excusable because in the 16-bit era one extra bit was considered worth the wrong semantics that `unsigned` types have in C++ for this kind of use.

Unfortunately now the `size_t` mistake cannot be fixed (because of backward compatibility) but why repeating the same mistake in another unrelated area?

Please note that probably the big mistake made was just the choice of the name `unsigned` (given its real meaning). If that type would have been named (more appropriately) `modulo` then probably it would be more evident why using a `modulo int` for the size of a string doesn't make any sense at all.

The name is irrelevant, what it counts is the semantic and `unsigned` simply has the wrong semantic for a counter or a size.

(*) I personally don't think it was a good enough reason even back then. If 32767 is not enough for a size now, then 65535 won't be enough really soon. Just a single bit (twice the value) was not, in my opinion, an acceptable price for such a bending of the semantic.

### EDIT

I've published a [video](https://youtu.be/4afySnY-XgY) in which I'm discussing in more details why I think that using and unsigned type for `size_t` was a design mistake in C++.

Slides can be downloaded from http://raksy.dyndns.org/unsigned.pdf

Comment: That's a rant, not an answer. Your claims need justification to make sense and provide any benefit to the reader.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: why do you think it's a rant? what am I supposedly ranting about?

Comment: Your opinion that size_t should have been signed

Comment: @M.M: it's not my opinion only... even Stroustrup agrees... see http://stackoverflow.com/q/10168079/320726

Comment: @6502: Would you be so kind to elaborate and give more light into your answer? If it is possible, would like to know more why you think that an `unsigned` counter "is not a valid excuse" and that it was a "mistake" and "partially excusable...".

[--edit] It seems I have posted this question after the reply with the link above. I'm currently reading it...[--end edit]

Comment: @6502: Firstly, Stroustrup is entitled to his opinion, but he's wrong. Secondly, whatever options are available, the decision has already been made a long time ago. Standard library sizes/counts are unsigned. Why on Earth this one's suddenly signed is indeed unclear. And adoption of unsigned types for counts/sizes has nothing to do with gaining an extra bit for value range.

Comment: @6502: Thirdly, the nature of unsigned types is consistent with the nature of open-closed ranges that dominate C and C++ iterator semantics. It has always been there in the very core of the language and it is not avoidable. It is not a matter of someone's decision, it is just how the world works. So, the original mistake was actually pushing forward *signed* types - a mistake made even before Stroustrup. Signed types belong in application-specific domains. The programming itself is unsigned, unsigned and unsigned, and only very rarely signed.

Comment: While I broadly agree that signed rather than unsigned types are beneficial in interfaces, In small systems there are times when you need the extra bit as you really do have some objects that take half the address space. The tradeoffs in a machine with a tiny address space are different.

Comment: @janm: there are not many cases in which a single array (of single bytes) needs to take more than half of your address space. And even less cases in which you cannot afford using multi-precision integers for that size (e.g. `long`). Using those cases to bend the rules for all other use cases, condemning future generations of programmers to stupid bugs because of it was in my opinion a questionable choice. Of course it could have been nice to have another integer type for non-negative integers (with correct semantics)... but `unsigned` is not that.

Comment: After having experience of more than a decade of programming, I dont use `unsigned` type for mathematical/logical operations, such as comparisons. I use `unsigned` only in case of bitwise operation. It saves me from lots of pitfalls due to automatic conversion from signed to unsigned, resulting in `-1` to become a very large value, for example .

Comment: ... Moreover, guys who advocate unsigned types dont realize that they dont really solve any problem; on the contrary, they hide them, making it even more difficult to find the bugs.

Comment: @Nawaz: I think this is the same conclusion that anyone using C++ for real coding for some time will come to. However there are many `unsigned-is-non-negative` obsessed that apparently just cannot think or understand (for reasons not very clear to me). I don't think I will lose my sleep because someone is wrong on the internet... ;-)

Comment: @6502 I agree, there are not many cases. But there are cases. I broadly agree with your argument (and upvoted your answer). Dealing with unsigned `size_t` vs. `ptrdiff_t` is a pain and a source of problems. I am not advocating unsigned types; I am just pointing out that in small systems it happens that single arrays do, occasionally, occupy half the address space. Thirty years ago I wrote code targeting PDP-11s, 6809s and Z80s. The tradeoffs were different then. From your "6502" name, I assume you understand those tradeoffs. Today similar tradeoffs are made in small embedded systems.

Comment: "The difference of two unsigned is unsigned", what do you suggest the result to be if it were a type used for "never negative"?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I simply wanted to make evident that "non-negative" is not the meaning of `unsigned`. Please listen to yourself when saying out loud "the difference of two non-negative values is a non-negative value" :-)

Comment: @6502 I understand what you were saying (which is why I revised my comment ^^). But I don't know a right type to use if we introduced a new type for "never negative". What would the type be? Would `nonneg - nonneg` be `long nonneg` ?

Comment: Perhaps the right semantics would be: The result type is `nonneg`, and behavior is undefined if the result would be negative. Same for addition if the result would overflow.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: the difference of two `nonneg int` should be a regular `int` (with UB when overflowing) or may be the difference of two `nonneg int` should be regular signed integer type large enough to ensure no overflow may occur.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, @6502, the problem here is that "difference" over natural numbers is not a total function. A type-safe, sound way to represent this situation would acknowledge this in the types. If I were to declare a user-defined numeric type for "non-negative integers", I'd make `operator/` return an `optional`. Or, as another equally valid option, I'd make it return a signed type, to signal that the result could be signed (but, in this case, there should be no automatic conversions between the two types).

Comment: This answer is wrong about the history. "unsigned" was not designed as the "modulo" type. In the initial years when C was still developing, there wasn't really much consideration of overflow in the language design. The arithmetic operators corresponded closely to the CPU instructions and were expected to behave as such. When C then got standardised, there was still a lot of variation in how signed overflow got handled, due to the different possible meanings of the sign bit, but unsigned overflow worked pretty much the same everywhere.

Comment: Because of that, the behaviour of unsigned would-be-overflow was standardised as well, and signed overflow was left undefined because given the varying representations of negative numbers, it made sense for overflow behaviour to depend on the representation used, there was no point in forcing two's complement for all implementations, especially for CPUs that might not support that natively. The compilers using that UB for optimisation purposes is a much later invention, too late to have been relevant to the language design.

Comment: @hvd: I never said that `unsigned` was deliberately designed as a "modulo" type. I simply stated that `unsigned` happens to be a "modulo" type and that given C++ semantics it was the wrong choice for the size of a container (even back then in 16-bit epoch). Keeping using `unsigned` when it should not be used even in C++14 when not forced to because of backward compatibility would be nonsense...

Comment: @6502 You say that `unsigned` is the wrong name, that it does not reflect the real meaning of the unsigned types. What do you mean by that, then? The point of my comments was that when it was designed, that was the only difference between signed and unsigned types, and the only meaning of the keywords.

Comment: @hvd: CPUs don't know about "type" of the data... they have unsigned or unsigned *operations*, but you're right that the name `unsigned` comes historically from that, and even if the operation was indeed a modulo one the name remained. I'll add a note about this...

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: In my opinion, the "non-negative" type should not support `operator-` to begin with. It should support only  bitwise operations. Or if at all it has to support `-` for non-negative too, then the result should be some *signed* type. Mathematically, `2-3` cannot produce a large value; if the result is not  `-1`, then you have not done `-`, it is something else.

Comment: @Nawaz: That statement, non-negative types should not support `operator -`, I find interesting.

Comment: @Nawaz They should support distance, not subtraction.  Using `-` for distance is a bad idea: clearly, overload `->` instead, so `a->b` is the distance between `a` and `b`.  ;)