# How can I simplify C++ functions with function pointers to class member functions?

Tags: c++

I give the following example to illustrate my question:

```
class Abc
{
public:
  int height();
  int width();
  int area();

};

typedef std::vector<class Abc> AbcArray;

void obtain_selected_list_based_on_area(AbcArray& objArray, 
    std::vector<int> &listIndexArray)
{
   std::vector<int> areaArray;
   for(int i=0; i<objArray.size(); i++)
            areaArray.push_back(objArray[i].area());

   function_select_list(areaArray,listIndexArray);
}

void obtain_selected_list_based_on_height(AbcArray& objArray, 
    std::vector<int> &listIndexArray)
{
   std::vector<int> areaArray;
   for(int i=0; i<objArray.size(); i++)
            areaArray.push_back(objArray[i].height());

   function_select_list(areaArray,listIndexArray);
}

void obtain_selected_list_based_on_width(AbcArray& objArray, 
    std::vector<int> &listIndexArray)
{
   std::vector<int> areaArray;
   for(int i=0; i<objArray.size(); i++)
            areaArray.push_back(objArray[i].width());

   function_select_list(areaArray,listIndexArray);
}
```

As you can see from the above code snippet, we decide to select the list based on three different criteria. In order to do that, we have to write three functions: `obtain_selected_list_based_on_area`, `obtain_selected_list_based_on_height`, and `obtain_selected_list_based_on_width`.
I just wondering how I can simplify it.
For me there one solutions. One is to use function pointer:

```
void obtain_select_list(AbcArray& objArray, std::vector<int> &listSel, FUN fun)
{
    std::vector<int> areaArray;
       for(int i=0; i<objArray.size(); i++)
                areaArray.push_back(objArray[i].width());

       function_select_list(areaArray,listIndexArray);

}
```

However, I cannot make it work because the function pointer is pointing to the member of a class.
Do you have some ideas on how to make it work? Moreover, any other solutions for this problem?

Comment: You could go all the way over to an IOC solution: instead of passing a function pointer, pass a reference to an instance of a class bearing a suitable method, and have `obtain_select_list()` invoke that method on the instance to do its work.

Comment: ... also, I'd pass the function as a compile-time (template) parameter. It's way faster to call a known function: a fnptr is about as slow as a virtual call!

Comment: Off-topic:  IMHO, you should be using `unsigned int` for `height`, `width`, and `area`.  The `int` type allows for negative numbers.  I have yet to see negative heights, widths or areas.

Comment: The question is very broad, allowing a multitude of possible approaches, and it's very vague, e.g. the `function_select_list` is not defined anywhere, there's no context. The simplest approach that preserves generality is probably to pass an ordinary function that retrieves a value from an `Abc`. Other approaches include passing member function pointer, member data pointer, an interface object, a simple selector value, etc. Voted to close as too broad.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Be careful, Some [people](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945872/finding-the-primary-numbers-in-an-array-of-pointer/40946175#comment69104163_40946175) are not agree. This is a open [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30395205/why-are-unsigned-integers-error-prone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly function pointers, but rather class method pointers.

Additionally, using C++11 range iteration makes the resulting syntax much simpler, and easier to read:

```
void obtain_selected_list_based_on(AbcArray& objArray, 
    std::vector<int> &listIndexArray,
    int (Abc::*get_something)())
)
{
   std::vector<int> areaArray;

   for (const auto &v:objArray)
            areaArray.push_back((v.*get_something)());

   function_select_list(areaArray,listIndexArray);
}
```

This can be invoked as:

```
obtain_selected_list_based_on(objArray,
                              listIndexArray,
                              &Abc::height);

// or

obtain_selected_list_based_on(objArray,
                              listIndexArray,
                              &Abc::width);

// or

obtain_selected_list_based_on(objArray,
                              listIndexArray,
                              &Abc::area);
```

Your class methods should probably be `const` themselves, which would change the parameter type to `int (Abc::*get_something)() const`.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work.

```
void <template T> obtain_select_list(AbcArray& objArray, std::vector<int> &listSel, T (*fun)(const Abc&))
{
    std::vector<T> areaArray;
       for(int i=0; i<objArray.size(); i++)
                areaArray.push_back(fun(objArray[i]));

       function_select_list(areaArray,listIndexArray);

}
```

Just to be more general i used a template one, so that if you need the function to return things different from an int you can still use it.

I wasn't able to test it, it compiles but i don't know it if works, but it should.

Comment: @Stargateur I guess he said: "Moreover, any other solutions for this problem?"

Comment: @Amadeus It's more close of his code. But indeed he asks anything.