# Crosses initialization of string and jump to label case

Tags: c++, menu, switch-statement

I am trying to do case menu for my program. And I always getting error of cross initialization, I have never before saw this error. Maybe someone could explain me what is happening wrong with my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

#define N_CARS 1

struct car{
    string model;
    int year;
    double price;
    bool available;
}cars [N_CARS];


void menu();
void mainMenu();

void writeToFile(ofstream &outputFile , const car& p)
{
    outputFile << p.model << " "
               << p.year << " "
               << p.price << " "
               << p.available<<"\n";
}

int choice1 = 0;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    menu();
    return 0;
}


void menu() {

    do {
        mainMenu();

        switch(choice1) {

            case 1:
                string mystr;
                string mystr2;
                string mystr3;

                int n;
                for (n=0; n<N_CARS; n++)
                {
                    cout << "Enter title: ";
                    getline (cin,cars[n].model);
                    cout << "Enter year: ";
                    getline (cin,mystr);
                    stringstream(mystr) >> cars[n].year;
                    cout << "Enter price: ";
                    getline (cin,mystr2);
                    stringstream(mystr2) >> cars[n].price;
                    cout << "Choose availability: ";
                    getline (cin,mystr3);
                    stringstream(mystr3) >> cars[n].available;
                }

                ofstream outputFile;
                outputFile.open("bla.txt", fstream::app);
                for (n=0; n<N_CARS; n++)
                    writeToFile(outputFile, cars[n]);
                outputFile.close();
                break;

            case 2:
                break;

            case 5:
                break;
        }

    } while(choice1 != 5);

}


void mainMenu(void) {

    cout << "Main Menu\n";
    cout << "1 - Enter Car\n";
    cout << "5 - Quit\n";
    cout << "Please choose: ";

    cin >> choice1;
}
```

Errors:

```
In function 'void menu()':
    [Error] jump to case label [-fpermissive]
    [Error] crosses initialization of 'std::ofstream outputFile'
    [Error] crosses initialization of 'std::string mystr3'
    [Error] crosses initialization of 'std::string mystr2'
    [Error] crosses initialization of 'std::string mystr'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`case` labels are really a lot like dreaded `goto` labels; they do not constitute a new scope. Consequently, a `switch` selecting the correct `case` label to jump to is, for better or worse, a lot like `goto` statement jumping to a label. The jump is not allowed to cross the initialisation of your various objects - exactly as the error messages say.

The cleanest thing for you to do would be to cut everything between `case 1:` and `break; case 2:` and paste it into a new **function** called something like `enterCar`.

```
void enterCar() {
    // code previously found between the case labels
}

// ...
switch(choice1) {
    case 1: enterCar(); break;
    case 2:
    // ...
}
```

A function constitutes a new scope in which your local objects can be correctly initialised. As a bonus, you are making first steps towards leaving all the spaghetti code behind you.

Comment: Its good refactor thank you. But now my enter model and enter year show up both instantly, I can not enter model, I dont know what happened, it worked before I start using case switch.

Comment: @NotsoPr0 - The input problem is described here: [Why does std::getline skip input after a formatted extraction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to enclose variable definitions within *case*-blocks with scope brackets {}.

Another thing: forget about *#define* for comple time constants, use *constexpr*:

```
constexpr size_t NumCars = 5;
```

Also note the *size_t*: for variables and constants describing sizes, e.g. array sizes or indices, use size_t.

Further, you include *cstdlib* and *stdlib.h*. Headerfiles from the C-standardlibrary should always be included with the c-prefix and .h-omission, so kick out the *stdlib.h*. You don't need it anyway.

Comment: *"Also note the size_t: for variables and constants describing sizes, e.g. array sizes or indices, use size_t."* - No, it's better to use a signed type for sizes, because otherwise you are effectively hiding errors with negative numbers.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10168569/3313064

Comment: okey, thanks for you advice. It is working now, but `enter title` cout goes together with `enter year` and I can not enter title now.

Comment: The linked post doesn't convince me. It states that there are pitfalls when doing arithmetic with signed integers and mixing in unsigned ones, but at the other hand doing arithmetic with unsigned integers and mixing in signed ones is basically the same. The point I'm trying to make: Think carefully whether you want to do signed oder unsigned arithmetic. For NotsoPr0: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553597/cin-and-getline-skipping-input

Comment: @TheTechel: Yes, mixing signed and unsigned is bad. You should therefore stay away from unsigned numbers *in general*. Unsigned numbers are only really useful for bit operations, i.e. when you are interested in individual bits; using them to avoid negative numbers when only positive ones are allowed is a bad idea.

Comment: A bad idea? Why?

Comment: There are reasons to use unsigned over signed arithmetic or vice versa, e.g. Indexing something vs. doing calculations with actual *values* like money and coordinates.