# C++ vector::size_type: signed vs unsigned; int vs. long

Tags: c++, vector, long-integer, multiplatform

I have been doing some testing of my application by compiling it on different platforms, and the shift from a 64-bit system to a 32-bit system is exposing a number of issues.

I make heavy use of vectors, strings, etc., and as such need to count them.  However, my functions also make use of 32-bit unsigned numbers because in many cases I need to explicitly consume a positive integer.

I'm having issues with seemingly simple tasks such as `std::min` and `std::max`, which may be more systemic.  Consider the following code:

```
uint32_t getmax()
{
    return _vecContainer.size();
}
```

Seems simple enough: I know that a vector can't have a negative number of elements, so returning an unsigned integer makes complete sense.

```
void setRowCol(const uint32_t &r_row; const uint32_t &r_col)
{
    myContainer_t mc;
    mc.row = r_row;
    mc.col = r_col;
    _vecContainer.push_back(mc);
}
```

Again, simple enough.

Problem:

```
uint32_t foo(const uint32_t &r_row)
{
    return std::min(r_row, _vecContainer.size());
}
```

This gives me errors such as:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:2589:1: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter '_Tp' ('unsigned long' vs. 'unsigned int')
min(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b)
```

I did a lot of digging, and on one platform vector::size_type is an 8 byte number.  However, by design I am using unsigned 4-byte numbers.  This is presumably causing things to be wacky because you cannot implicitly convert from an 8-byte number to a 4-byte number.

The solution was to do this the old fashioned weay:

```
#define MIN_M(a,b) a < b ? a : b
return MIN_M(r_row, _vecContainer.size());
```

Which works dandy.  But the systemic issue remains: when planning for multiple platform support, how do you handle instances like this?  I could use size_t as my standard size, but that adds other complications (e.g. moving from one platform which supports 64 bit numbers to another which supports 32 bit numbers at a later date).  The bigger issue is that size_t is unsigned, so I can't update my signatures:

```
size_t foo(const size_t &r_row)
// bad, this allows -1 to be passed, which I don't want
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I had read somewhere that size_t was signed, and I've since been corrected.  So far it looks like this is a limitation of my own design (e.g. 32-bit numbers vs. using std::vector::size_type and/or size_t).

Comment: If you see e.g. [this `std::vector` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) you will see that `size_type` is usually a [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) whose type is an implementation specific **unsigned** integer. If you want a type that denotes a non-negative size, you should either use `std::size_t` or for a container `size_type` itself.

Comment: `std::min(r_row, _vecContainer.size());` You can either make r_row the correct type for comparison, or explicitly cast it to the correct type.

Comment: Also, what makes you think `size_t` is a signed type? That using it will allow `-1` to be passed?

Comment: You may find [`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) an interesting read.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but passing numeric types by const& is overdesign. Just pass them by value.

Comment: *"I know that a vector can't have a negative number of elements, so returning an unsigned integer makes complete sense."* - No, it does not. The fact that the standard library uses unsigned types to represent sizes is due to historical reasons. Do not do that yourself. Always use signed integers unless you are performing bit-wise operations. If necessary, cast the container sizes to `int`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10168569/3313064

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yes, there are issues with unsigned numbers, but casting to `int` isn’t the right answer. Even on 64-bit systems, `int` is often 32 bits. If you’re dealing with `char`s, then you really can have more than 2^31 - 1 of them, in memory, and this will cause problems.

Comment: @ChristianHackl If you want to cast a `size_t` to a signed type, `ptrdiff_t` would be better than `int`. On LP64 implementations, `size_t` is 64 bits, but `int` is 32 bits. Last I checked, Google recommends `ptrdiff_t` followed by a check that the result is non-negative, while Microsoft recommends `rsize_t` followed by a check that the result is below some maximum value intended to detect wraparound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An answer in the form of a set of tidbits:

1. Instead of relying on the compiler to deduce the type, you can explicitly specify the type when using function templates like `std::min<T>`.  For example: `std::min<std::uint32_t>(4, my_vec.size());`
2. Turn on all the compiler warnings related to signed versus unsigned comparisons and implicit narrowing conversions.  Use brace initialization where you can, as it will treat narrowing conversions as errors.
3. If you explicitly want to use 32-bit values like `std::uint32_t`, I'd try to find the minimal number of places to explicitly convert (i.e., static_cast) the "sizes" to the smaller types.  You don't want casts everywhere, but if you're using library container sizes internally and you want your API to use `std::uint32_t`, explicitly cast at the API boundaries so that a user of your class never has to worry about doing the conversion themselves.  If you can keep the conversions to just a couple places, it becomes practical to add run-time checks (i.e., assertions) that the size has not actually outgrown the range of the smaller type.
4. If you don't care about the exact size, use `std::size_t`, which is almost certainly identical to `std::XXX::size_type` for all of the standard containers.  It's theoretically possible for them to be different, but it doesn't happen in practice.  In most contexts, `std::size_t` is less verbose that `std::vector::size_type`, so it makes a good compromise.
5. Lots of people (including many people on the C++ standards committee) will tell you to avoid unsigned values even for sizes and indexes.  I understand and respect their arguments, but I don't find them persuasive enough to justify the extra friction at the interface with the standard library.  Whether or not it's an historical artifact that `std::size_t` is unsigned, the fact is that the standard library uses unsigned sizes extensively.  If you use something else, your code ends up littered with implicit conversions, all of which are potential bugs.  Worse, those implicit conversions make turning on the compiler warnings impractical, so all those latent bugs remain relatively invisible.  (And even if you know your sizes will never exceed the smaller type, being forced to turn of the compiler warnings for signedness and narrowing means you could miss bugs in completely unrelated parts of the code.)  Match the types of the APIs you're using as much as possible, assert and explicitly convert when necessary, and turn on all the warnings.
6. Keep in mind that `auto` is not a panacea.  `for (auto i = 0; i < my_vec.size(); ++i) ...` is just as bad as `for (int i ...`.  But if you generally prefer algorithms and iterators to raw loops, `auto` will get you pretty far.
7. With division you must never divide unless you know the denominator is not 0.  Similarly, with unsigned integral types, you must never subtract unless you know the subtrahend is smaller than or equal to the original value.  If you can make that a habit, you can avoid the bugs that the always-use-a-signed-type folks are concerned about.

Answer (score 6):

One way to deal with this is to use

```
std::vector<Type>::size_type
```

as the underlying type of your function parameters/returns, or `auto` returns if using C++14.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that won't work. Again, by design some of my internal variables are uin32_t.  If I use `std::vector<T>::size_type` there is no guarantee that it will still be 32 bits.   I just realized I never called this out; question updated.

Comment: @tendim Then you're a bit out of luck, as the design is not the best in this case. The only thing you can do is to force a cast. When using generic types it's a good idea to use platform-independent data types as well, don't just stick to `uint32_t`.

Comment: thanks for confirming what I was thinking so far..  Using the macro is the "cleanest" solution I've found to date.